# Image greyscale on hover + <p> visible only on hover

Tags: image, css, hover, mouseover

I would like to achieve what i wrote in the title, simultaneously.

What i have is a div that is width:100% (container) and contains 4 images inside of a div, 25% each (grid), with a description layer inside (on) it - called desc, for the overall dimensions, and span, for the mere text.

Here is the CSS:

```
.grid-container {
    width: 85%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
.grid {
    width: 25%;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}

.grid img {
    border-radius: 50%;
    transition: .4s -webkit-filter linear;
    -webkit-transition: background .5s ease 50ms;
    transition: background .5s ease 50ms;
}

.grid img:hover {
    filter: url(filters.svg#grayscale);
  /* Firefox 3.5+ */
  filter: gray;
  /* IE6-9 */
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(1);
  /* Google Chrome & Safari 6+ */
  background: rgba(168, 202, 217, .6)
}

.desc {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 26%;
    width: 87%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0%;
    left: 0%;
    border-radius: 50%;

}

.desc:hover {
    background: rgba(168, 202, 217, .6)
}

.desc span {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
text-align: center;
margin-top: 37%;
position: absolute;
left: 0;
top: 0;
font-size: 16px;
opacity: 0;
-webkit-transition: opacity .5s ease 50ms;
transition: opacity .5s ease 50ms;
color: #fff !important;
}

.desc span:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

So, what i want to achieve is to make the image go grayscale when hovered, while making the description visible. Description has a background color aswell (can i apply that to the image instead, along with the greyscale filter?)
The problem is that the description this way occupies the whole image, so the hover would be considered by the description only and not the image.

Any clues on how i can achieve what i want? Thanks for your attentio

Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple, put both elements in the same container. For example,

```
.grid:hover img {
  filter: url(filters.svg#grayscale);
}

.grid:hover .desc span {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: than you very much, your solution worked like a charm!

Comment: Thank you. Other solution below is also a good one, and in some cases the only possibility. But it is also harder to debug, to keep track of and override (cascading in CSS). Also, if you found my answer helpful and solution to your problem, you can mark it as accepted answer - so others can find it easier.

Comment: Done that! Thanks again to both of you!

Answer (score 0):

If your description is an immediate following sibling of the image, you can use the immediate following-sibling selector:

```
.grid img:hover + .descr{display: block; background: whatever;}
```

(selects the element with the `class="descr"` once the mouse hovers over the image)

HTML structure for this to work:

```
<div>
    <img>
    <p class="descr">
</div>
```